# python heroku socket server

Tags: python, sockets, heroku, server

I've created a Python simple server.py and client.py chat.

I was wondering if it is possible to deploy server.py on heroku so that it's always running and I can access the server from any client.py at any time.

I've tried deploying the simple server.py to heroku but it doesn't print anything in the logs section and it seems like it didn't even start the code as it should print "server on" but it doesn't.

I think that I'm missing something in the Procfile or in the requirements.txt file.
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Did u solved that issue @Beyram ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `heroku ps:scale web=1` so your `dyno` can work